# Getting modifier keys (Alt, Ctrl) to work together with ISO_Level3_Shift

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, wayland

I have altered quite a bit my keyboard layout using two levels of shift keys. Basically now, I have 3 layers on my keyboard. In order to do so I used the ISO_Level3_Shift and ISO_Level5_Shift.

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys xkb_symbols "basic" {
  name[Group1]= "Thinkpad US (portuguese AltGr dead keys)";

  include "us(basic)"

  // Modkeys
  // -------
  // POP
  key <AC10>  { type[Group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL", [ ISO_Level3_Shift, ISO_Level3_Shift, ISO_Level3
_Shift, ISO_Level3_Shift, question, question, NoSymbol ] };
  modifier_map Mod3 { <AC10> };

  // SNAP
  key <CAPS>  { type[Group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL", [ ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5
_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift, colon, colon, NoSymbol ]   };
  key <AC11>  { type[Group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL", [ ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5
_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift, semicolon, semicolon, NoSymbol ]   };
  modifier_map Mod3 { <CAPS>, <AC11> };

  replace key <ESC> { [ Caps_Lock ] };


  key.type[Group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC" ;

  // middle row
  // ----------
  // asdfghjkl
  // [SNAP]
  key <AC01> { [ a, A, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, asciitilde, asciitilde, NoSymbol ] };
  key <AC02> { [ s, S, Home, Home, equal, equal, NoSymbol ] };
  key <AC03> { [ d, D, Prior, Prior, apostrophe, apostrophe, NoSymbol ] };
 key <AC04> { [ f, F, Next, Next, quotedbl, quotedbl, NoSymbol ] };
  key <AC05> { [ g, G, End, End, minus, minus, NoSymbol ] };
  key <AC06> { [ h, H, Left, Left, plus, plus, NoSymbol ] };
  key <AC07> { [ j, J, Down , Down, comma, comma, NoSymbol] };
  key <AC08> { [ k, K, Up, Up, period, period, NoSymbol ] };
  key <AC09> { [ l, L, Right, Right, Escape, Escape, NoSymbol ] };
  // [POP]
  // [SNAP]

  // Space key
  // ---------
  key <SPCE> { [ space, space, grave, grave, Tab, Tab, NoSymbol ] };

};
```

This works as expect except when using the normal modifier keys like Alt or Control or Windows keys.

For instance, Space is set to give Tab when pressed together with the SNAP [;] (so SNAP+Space = Tab) key, but if I press Alt+SNAP+Space I don't get the expected behaviour from Alt+Tab as expected.

How can I achieve the proper functionality?